# Live Link Face - Head rotation variables (HeadYaw HeadPitch HeadRoll) not working despite "Stream head rotation" toggled On

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, unreal-engine5

Steps to reproduce:

Download **Live Link Face 1.2.0(1)** on Apple iphone OS 15.5 (tested on 11 pro and 13, as well as Ipad 4th gen, all experience same exact issue)

After download, launch settings and toggle On "Stream head rotation"

[image]

and then enable display  "blendshape data".

[image]

At this point upon viewing the camera, you can see all values for HeadYaw, HeadPitch, HeadRoll are all zero for no good reason! [image]

This is an issue because I cannot move my meta humans head at all. What is going wrong? How can I better determine what exactly is wrong with this application?

The Stream Head Rotation does not appear to be working as expected. Please help Thank you in advance.

Permissions seem fine[image]

I believe all information here is enough to reproduce by anyone with an iphone.

Comment: Did you tried to contact Epic Games assistance which may be more suitable for this kind of problem.

Comment: What phone number?

Comment: The problem seems to be known on [Epic forum](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/live-link-face-head-movement-not-working/568804)

Comment: details here are more verbose , additionally, I posted in their forum and it has not been approved, making stackoverflow a better channel at this point to get feedback and ultimately resolve this particular issue. Maybe a IOS app update is required, which has not yet been published to app store at this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in Live Link Face version 1.2.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).